# Interrupt pin type on the 6502

Tags: 6502, interrupt, microprocessor, 65c02

I have a really basic question. I have to design an 65C02-based personal computer for a school project. I have to draw my own footprint for the 65C02. My question is what type of pin is the IRQB (Interrupt) pin? I know what the purpose of the pin is. I have no idea if it is Input or Output... or Bidirectional. The datasheets have no mentions on what each pin is as far as type.

Comment: You should add a link to the particular data sheet you're using so we can tell you if you're reading it correctly. (It would be a bit of a weird data sheet if it didn't explain enough about the pin to determine if it's an input or ouput, unless it's a summary or overview rather than a proper data sheet.)

Comment: I think I'm using a summary! It is only 12 pages long...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interrupt pin is an input.

Answer (score 5):

The [W65C02 data sheet](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Western%20Design/W65C02S.pdf) does explain it (p. 9):

> 3.4     Interrupt Request (IRQB)
>
> The Interrupt Request (IRQB) input signal is used to request that an interrupt sequence be initiated. The program
>   counter (PC) and Processor Status Register (P) are pushed onto the stack and the IRQB disable (I) flag is set to a "1"
>   disabling further interrupts before jumping to the interrupt handler. These values are used to return the processor to
>   its original state prior to the IRQB interrupt. The IRQB low level should be held until the interrupt handler clears
>   the interrupt request source. When Return from Interrupt (RTI) is executed the (I) flag is restored and a new
>   interrupt can be handled. If the (I) flag is cleared in an interrupt handler, nested interrupts can occur. The Wait-for-
>   Interrupt (WAI) instruction may be used to reduce power and synchronize with, as an example timer interrupt
>   requests.

So it not only tells you that this is an input signal, it also explains how long it should be held at low level.

The General Timing Diagram (Figure 6-3, p. 26) has some more timing information for IRQB.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen that particular datasheet, there are multiple versions. I will follow that datasheet in the future as it is more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

An interrupt pin of a CPU will always be an **Input**.

After all, it's whole purpose is to tell the CPU about an interrupt pending. Wouldn't work if it's an output, would it?

Comment: Some microcontrollers use bidirectional pins for interrupts or even, for some Motorola HC11 variants, the *reset* line(!?).  If a Computer Operating Properly timer (watchdog) fires, it will pull the reset line low, thus allowing it to reset other devices at the same time.  I don't care for the design, but it does indicate that such pins not need be purely inputs.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen situations like those. That's why I was so confused. Thank you!

Comment: @supercat Well, you already put the distinction in your comment: They are micro**contollers**, not micro processors. Their pins aren't CPU pins but system busses. A Timer is already an external component pulling the reset line low that happens to be on this controller/SoC. Not so a single CPU, like the 6502. While it often doesn't matter to distinguish between a microprocessor and more integrated chips, this is one were it does.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The 68HC11 in question was often used as a microprocessor, with code stored in an external ROM.or RAM (as it was in the application where I was in fact using it), and the /RESET input was in fact being used as a /RESET pin, but it's driven low for IIRC two cycles if a watchdog timeout occurs.

Comment: @supercat Haven't argued about. I'm well aware of the that chip. Build one a (somewhat) successful device base on two of them. Still, no matter if an external ROM is used or not, it'll continues to be a Controller/SoC, not just a microprocessor.